# How to pass data to d3js using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3js graph. In the example, it gets the data like this :

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

And the data.tsv file is something like this :

```
letter  frequency
A   .08167
B   .01492
C   .02782
D   .04253
E   .12702
F   .02288
G   .02015
```

Suppose I have a List of tuples like this :

```
public class myData {
public string x {get; set;}
public int y {get; set;}
}

myData data1 = new myData("A", 1);
myData data2 = new myData("B", 3);

List<myData> list1 = new List<myData>()
        {
         data1, data2
        };
```

How can I pass this `list1` to d3js? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways... Is this data dyamically generated?

If not - you could just put it in a file.

If so - you can return as JSON using the Json() method in a controller, then consume with an AJAX call, or you could just spit it out in your view in the javascript like `var data = @(Model.Data)`

Comment: Is passing data  like var data = @(Model.Data) enough?  Because in above js, there are lines which does mapping or things like that. Thanks.

Comment: Well yes you will obviously still have to map the data... otherwise how will it know which fields to use? We can't do that bit for you - it depends what you want to graph.... Your question seemed to be about how to use data from the backend (C#) in the frontend (javascript) which my questions answers. For help with D3JS look at their website, they have great documentation and examples: https://d3js.org/